# Why is my minibuffer scrolling and preventing me from seeing emacs asking me questions?

Tags: minibuffer, terminal-emacs, scrolling

My new emacs is scrolling minibuffer text so that I can't see simple stuff, like when emacs asks if I want to save changes to a file before exiting.

Doing this both in a mac window or in Terminal.

Using emacs 25.0.50, built for mac using homebrew. Installed ember-mode and elpa for packages, but that's about it.

Haven't found help via google or SO ... perhaps my search-fu is weak today. Any advice out there on how to debug / fix?

Comment: Something similar happened to me when there was a hook that ran for just any command and printed something into a messages buffer. Just to make sure: does message buffer display anything that would suggest it is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a development snapshot of Emacs?  If so, perhaps you were hit by [Emacs bug #21403](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21403), which makes the prompt for `y-or-n-p` invisible.

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. Built via homebrew. M-x version says:

GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS appkit-1348.17 Version 10.10.5 (Build 14F27)) of 2015-09-02

Comment: Aha, looks like I built via homebrew with a --HEAD argument. Serves me right. Rebuilding as soon as I'm off airplane wifi. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the scroll variable has been set. Unset it as following in your init.el file:

```
(setq minibuffer-scroll-window nil)
```

which is the default anyway.

Comment: Set this - didn't make a difference, sadly.